# Will Limit and Offset make Room DB search faster

Tags: android, optimization, search, pagination, android-room

I want to optimize the Room database search with [pagination](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview?authuser=1). There is a couple of ways to handle the pager data:

1. Return all records and filter the result. E.g.

   allResults.filter {
   it.status in statusList
   }
2. Return some records (pagination) using Limit and Offset in the query

   @Query("SELECT * FROM Table  WHERE status IN (:statusList) LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset")

For network-related traffic, the 2nd option is preferable. However, the Room database is local, does it have any effect on the speed of search or memory usage?

Answer (score 1):

Not really, it still has to effectively select all the appropriate rows to be able to ascertain which rows that the LIMIT and OFFSET apply to.

However, using SQLite to filter the results as such, may well be faster then trying to do the filtering with the collection/objects retrieved via Room.

You may wish to consider looking at  https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html  *primarily it is the WHERE clause that is prominent when optimizing a query* and of course the available/usable indexes.